# add emails from spreadsheet to google groups (regular gmail account)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-groups

I basically collect responses from a Google Form and put them into a Google Spreadsheet . It has timestamp , name and email column . I would like to add all these emails(they all are google account emails) into my Google Group(where I am the owner, note that I have a normal Gmail account). People cannot directly join my group , they can only join on invite .

I want to write a Google App Script code for adding members into my Google Group from the Spreadsheet. It is compulsory to use a normal Gmail account.

I tried to do it with the Admin SDK directory API for Google App Script , but it was not working. As I think , it is only for Google Workspace accounts.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups)?

Comment: @a-burge . yes i have had a look at the documentation . But there I only see methods to retrieve information , but there seem to be no methods to add members in a group

Answer (score 2):

Admin SDK Directory API as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups) does not contain an endpoint to have this done using a Gmail.com account. On the other hand, the Advanced Admin SDK Directory Service has an endpoint to do it and is described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#add_group_member) but as mentioned at the top of the page a Google Workspace account/domain is required:

> The Admin SDK Directory service allows you to use the Admin SDK's Directory
> API in Apps Script. This API gives *administrators of
> Google Workspace domains* (including resellers) the ability to manage devices,
> groups, users, and other entities in their domains.

Taking the above into consideration it can be confirmed that as of the date of this response adding members to a Google Group using Google Apps Script and a Gmail.com account is NOT possible.

As an option, you may want to submit a Feature Request [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features)